# ASP.NET CSHTML ignores <br>

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

Input:

```
Text<br><br>text
```

Expected display:

```html
Text

Text
```

Real display:

```
Text
Text
```

CSHTML:

```
<div class="row">
   @Html.Raw(item.Text)
</div>
```

Where item text: `string Text = "Text<br><br>text"`

Edit

Works on Microsoft Edge, not on Firefox.

Comment: Have you checked the output, because I sincerely doubt `Html.Raw(...)` is programmed to remove breaks.

Comment: In raw html it has <br><br> and Microsoft Edge displays it properly, but Firefox refuses to work.

Comment: May be Firefox sees `<br>`as white space and collapses them (that would be a bug). Have you tried to have a `&nbsp;` between the breaks.?

Comment: @PoulBak can you give full reply so I can mark your answer as solution? Now it works perfectly.

Comment: @PoulBak false alarm, &nbsp; adds additional space to the bottom text.

Comment: You should only add one `no-breaking-space`, between the breaks, like this: "Text<br>&nbsp;<br>text"

Comment: @PoulBak that means I have to come up with algorithm that detects if it is the last <br>, it should not add another no-breaking-space.